# How i can add Admob to listview ?

Tags: android, listview, admob

I have a problem about Admob to listView
1. Can i add Admob to listview like below ?

row 1 
 
row 2 
ads  
row 3 
row 4 
ads

i'm add Admob code into Adapter.But have a problem when slide down.
this error code
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView cannot be cast to com.xxxxxxx.aaaaaaa.view.ItemList

this code getView in adapter

`if(position % k == 0){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_small,null);
            AdView adView = (AdView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            return adView;
        } else {
            final ItemList cardNews;
            if (convertView != null ) {
                cardNews = (ItemList) convertView;
            } else {
                cardNews = new ItemList(parent.getContext());
            }
            cardNews.setTvTitle(dao.get(position).getTitle());
            return cardNews;
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your code will surely throw ClassCastException because you are trying to reuse `adView` as `ItemList`.

```
if(position % k == 0){
   return adView; // Now convert view is Adview
} else {
      if (convertView != null ) { /// Yes it valid because AdView is not null
         cardNews = (ItemList) convertView; // This is invalid, 
                                            // AdView can't be ItemList
  }
}
```

Now the question arise why this issue come on scroll? so the answer is because Adapter try to reuse Views on scrolling which are already drawn on screen.

So what is a solution?
- Solution is simple, you can use ViewType as per your need.